# Checking if the same user has 2 terminals open

Tags: bash

I'm trying to detect if 1 user has 2 terminal sessions open.
How can this be achieved?

What I tried is the following:

```
linuxName="$(id -u -n)"
for user in "$@"; do
    if echo "$who" | grep -q "$linuxName"; then
        echo "[WARNING] You're already logged in";
        closeSessionIfNotRoot
    fi;
done;
```

Comment: Look for multiple results in the output of `who | grep theirusername`

Comment: Or `w theirusername`

Comment: I've posted what i tried so far @Barmar. However i do not get the warning. How would i return it as a number?

Comment: PIpe the output to `wc -l`

Comment: It's not clear which user you're trying to check. `$linuxName` is the current user, `$@` are the arguments to the script.

Comment: How are you calling the script, what are the arguments? Is `$who` supposed to be `$user`?

Comment: @Niveus answer is  below with your script, just need it to adjust some things

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
linuxName="$(id -un)"
for user in "$@"; do
    process_counter=$(pgrep -u "$user" bash 2>&1 | wc -l)
    if [[ "$user" == $(who | grep -o "$linuxName") ]]; then
        echo "[WARNING] You're already logged in $user"
        if [[ "$process_counter" -gt 1 ]]; then
            ((process_counter--))
            pgrep -u "$user" bash | tail -"$process_counter" | 
                xargs -I % kill -9 %
            echo "closed other terminals: $user"
        fi
    fi
done
```

- `script` +`arguments`[in this case, users_names], example, `./script alex zara sophia`

##### Explain answer

###### Count terminals open by user and save to variable process_counter

```sh
process_counter=$(pgrep -u "$user" bash 2>&1 | wc -l)
```

- `2>1` REDIRECTS output error to NO SHOW. this in case you wrote a **user_name** that doesn't exist in the system.
- `pgrep -u $user bash | wc -l` returns number of terminals open. `u $user` is for returning the process from that user, so this uniq.
- `pgrep` shows the process you are searching for,e.g., `pgreg bash` returns a lists of process IDs

returns:

```
363570
369836
370113
```

###### this checks if the `$user` --> `./file alex zara` is the same as in terminal `$linuxName`

```sh
[[ "$user" == $(who | grep -o "$linuxName") ]]
```

- `grep -o` only returns the username `alex` instead of `alex :1 2021-07....`
- `[[ ]]` is to make comparisons in bash

###### **xargs** is for pasing previous argument to a loop

```sh
tail -"$process_counter" | xargs -I % kill -9 %
```

- `tail -$process_counter` is for showing the last terminals open

```
363570
369836 #return only this
370113 #return only this
```

remember that we REST minus 1 to process_counter because we want to leave 1 terminal open, this is done with `((process_counter--))`.
So 3 terminals open - 1 terminal = 2 terminals to close.

now we loop with XARGS

```
363570
369836 #CLOSE THIS kill -9 369836
370113 #CLOSE THIS kill -9 370113
```

- `-I` arguments  tells **xargs** to assign a variable, represented with symbol `%`. but this symbol can be anything,like `#,$,` and then what we want to do is kill each process, so that's why `kill -9 %`

Answer (score 0):

sort count and filter these that have more then 2.

```
id -u -n | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 2'
```

Answer (score -1):

Check `limits.conf` which is configuration file for the `pam_limits` module.
In that file, you can define `maxlogins` as the maximum number of logins for a user (this limit does not apply to user with uid=0)

See https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html.